i want to set up two universal robot ur5e arms with ros 2 and ur_robotic_driver package.Why does the controler fail to load?
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, GroupAction, TimerAction
from launch_ros.actions import PushRosNamespace, Node
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
import os

def generate_launch_description():

    ld = LaunchDescription()

    # Path to the UR control launch file
    ur_launch_file = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('ur_robot_driver'),
        'launch',
        'ur_control.launch.py'
    )
    
    # Parameters for the Robots
    robot29_params = {
        'namespace' : 'robot29',
        'ur_type' : 'ur5e',
        'robot_ip' : '131.246.27.29',
        'kinematics_params_file' : '/home/kokobot/robot_calibrations/ur5e029_calibration.yaml',
        'initial_joint_controller' : 'joint_trajectory_controller',
        'script_command_port' : '50004',
        'reverse_port' : '50001',
        'script_sender_port' : '50002',
        'trajectory_port' : '50003'
    }

    robot30_params = {
        'namespace' : 'robot30',
        'ur_type' : 'ur5e',
        'robot_ip' : '131.246.27.30',
        'kinematics_params_file' : '/home/kokobot/robot_calibrations/ur5e030_calibration.yaml',
        'initial_joint_controller' : 'joint_trajectory_controller',
        'script_command_port' : '50014',
        'reverse_port' : '50011',
        'script_sender_port' : '50012',
        'trajectory_port' : '50013'
    }

    # Include the launch file for the first robot
    ur5e29_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(ur_launch_file),
        launch_arguments=robot29_params.items(),
    )

    # Push namespace for the first robot
    ur5e29_launch = GroupAction(
        actions=[
            PushRosNamespace('robot29'),
            ur5e29_launch,
        ]
    )
    ld.add_action(ur5e29_launch)

    # Include the launch file for the second robot
    ur5e30_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(ur_launch_file),
        launch_arguments=robot30_params.items(),
    )

    # Push namespace for the second robot
    ur5e30_launch = GroupAction(
        actions=[
            PushRosNamespace('robot30'),
            ur5e30_launch,
        ]
    )
    ld.add_action(ur5e30_launch)
    
    # Delay for the spawner of the first robot controllers
    robot29_spawner = TimerAction(
        period=5.0,  # Delay in seconds
        actions=[
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner",
                arguments=["joint_trajectory_controller"],
                namespace="robot29",
                output="screen"
            )
        ]
    )
    #ld.add_action(robot29_spawner)

    # Delay for the spawner of the second robot controllers
    robot30_spawner = TimerAction(
        period=5.0,  # Delay in seconds
        actions=[
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner",
                arguments=["joint_trajectory_controller"],
                namespace="robot30",
                output="screen"
            )
        ]
    )
    #ld.add_action(robot30_spawner)

    return ld

this yields the following error:
[spawner-9] [FATAL] [1729517767.440018738] [robot29.spawner_forward_position_controller]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-7] [FATAL] [1729517767.446675930] [robot29.spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-17] [FATAL] [1729517767.449562930] [robot30.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-16] [FATAL] [1729517767.450299901] [robot30.spawner_joint_trajectory_controller]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-8] [FATAL] [1729517767.464347098] [robot29.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[spawner-18] [FATAL] [1729517767.471564901] [robot30.spawner_forward_position_controller]: Could not contact service /controller_manager/list_controllers
[ERROR] [spawner-17]: process has died [pid 41565, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 joint_state_broadcaster io_and_status_controller speed_scaling_state_broadcaster force_torque_sensor_broadcaster --ros-args -r __ns:=/robot30'].
[ERROR] [spawner-9]: process has died [pid 41531, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --inactive forward_position_controller --ros-args -r __ns:=/robot29'].
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 41526, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_trajectory_controller -c /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --ros-args -r __ns:=/robot29'].
[ERROR] [spawner-8]: process has died [pid 41528, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 joint_state_broadcaster io_and_status_controller speed_scaling_state_broadcaster force_torque_sensor_broadcaster --ros-args -r __ns:=/robot29'].
[ERROR] [spawner-16]: process has died [pid 41560, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_trajectory_controller -c /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --ros-args -r __ns:=/robot30'].
[ERROR] [spawner-18]: process has died [pid 41589, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager /controller_manager --controller-manager-timeout 10 --inactive forward_position_controller --ros-args -r __ns:=/robot30'].


Welcome at RSE. Please format your question properly the next time (I fixed that now for you).

The error messages tell you that the spawners can't reach the ros2_control_node. I guess there is a problem with the namespaces: As far as I have seen now, the ur_control.launch.py does not support namespaceing of the ros2_control_node.
You have posted only half of the log, did both of the ros2_control_nodes started correctly? What services do you see (ros2 service list)?
